# Enable touch on Dynamically created Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in which i created 1 to 10 divs dynamically now i want to drag them from touch not from mouse or cursor. Now how to make these dynamically created touchable and dragable at the same time. any help

```
<div id="cardPile"></div>



var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
      numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );



      for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {


                $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
                  containment: '#content',
                  stack: '#cardPile div',
                  cursor: 'move',
                  revert: true
                } );



              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean you want to add an event handler for touch to a div that has been created dynamically you need to use the .on event handler for example

`$('div').on("touch", function(){});`

Also you might want to do it for click too:

`$('div').on("click", function(){});`

This is called event delegation and works for dynamically added elements. You can use the MDN to discover all the touch and drag related events and bind them to respond the way you want them to.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i also want that the div should move or drag on touch not on mouse hover

Comment: @User42590 Ok, if you visit the Mozilla Developer Network and look at the touch events page you should be able to experiment with some of the stuff you find on there and achieve what you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/